# Is it correct to take density of water as 1 g/cm3 for physics numericals?

Tags: mass, density, weight

In solving physics or physical chemistry questions, generally we take density of water as 1 gm/cm^3 or 1000 KG/m3 and according to our daily experience it is correct as often times we have experienced that 1 litre of water weighs 1 KG but that's the issue. Water has weight of 1 KG for 1 Litre and not mass of 1 KG for 1 Litre so doesn't that mean that our numerical solutions in physics or chemistry are wrong?

Clarification:

I think people were getting confused with usage of weight and mass words.
When I refer to 1 KG of weight then I don't mean weight of mass 1 KG but weight of 1 KG we use in daily life for things such as when you go to a shop and buy things. Now, our daily life weight is actually force and it is 1 N = 1 KG ( KG used in daily life) and so, with that logic

1 KG (daily life KG)=(mass) * g = 1N

Hence actual mass of 1 KG water is lot less than 1 KG hence density should be less than 1 KG/ litre

Clarification 2:

I get it now, thanks everyone, 1 KG of weight in real life is actually 9.81 N of force, I had assumed it was 1 N of force but it is wrong.

Comment: Density is defined as mass per unit volume, so yes a density of $1000$ Kg/L is defined as $1000$ Kg of mass in one liter. This water will then have a weight per liter of $9800$ newtons.

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, but in reality we know that weight of water for 1 L is 1 KG so we are wrong, right? Because our daily 1 KG is 1 Newtons of force.

Comment: Scales that measure in "kg" measure in units of "gravity times kg" $g\,\mathrm{kg}\approx9.81\,\mathrm{N}.$ Precise scales will be calibrated to the local gravity so they correctly read the mass of whatever you put on them.

Comment: You don't need a spring balance. You can also use a beam balance and that will work and give you the same answer.

Comment: @HTNW yes, that's what I am saying, the gravity factor being multiplied gives us a force and so if an object has weight of 1 KG this means mg= 1 hence this is actually 1 N of of force meaning that it can't be used directly for density formula, but we know that 1 litre of water has weight of 1 KG and we are using that to get density of 1000Kg/m^3 which is wrong

Comment: @HTNW at least not when g doesn't equals to 1 which is not the value on earth surface

Comment: @Triatticus  I am not familiar with "K" and "G" in contrast to "k" and "g" as prefix and unit.  "K" and "G" are not standard and so will produce ambiguity and confusion in the heads of people like me.  Since I've never heard of them, I don't know what they mean other than the fact that they are *not* the same as "k" and "g".  If they were, your comment would be incorrect.   Moral:  don't use non-standard symbols.

Comment: @garyp while it's common to use a lowercase k for kilogram, it's technically correct to use uppercase letters for the prefixes larger than base units (G for giga, H for hecto, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing mass and weight. "Mass" is the amount of stuff a body is made of. It is measured in $kg$. "Weight" is a force that acts on a body due to some acceleration, most typically Earth's gravity. It's measured in Newton.

Everyday language is unfortunately sloppy about this. The mass of $1l$ of water is $1kg$. It's weight is $9.81N$ (physically speaking). If you take $1l$ of water far into space, it's mass will still be $1kg$ (since it's still the same amount of stuff) but it's weight will be $0N$ since there is no gravity acting on it.

[http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mass.html#:~:text=The%20weight%20of%20an%20object,SI%20unit%20is%20the%20newton](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mass.html#:%7E:text=The%20weight%20of%20an%20object,SI%20unit%20is%20the%20newton).

Comment: I know that, but I said that the weight we read on earth as 1 KG is 1 N of force, isn't it? In that regard, actual mass would be weight/g, but we are using weight of 1 KG for density formula which wrong

Comment: You are misunderstanding the doubt to lack of basic knowledge.

Comment: @Ritanshu weight is the force exerted by an object under the influence of gravity, so no a mass of 1 kilogram is *not* one newton but $9.81$ newtons (on the surface of the earth).

Comment: @Ritanshu: sorry, you are wrong. The weight of 1 liter of water is 9.81 N and its mass is 1 kg. If you disagree, please provide a reference of where your "basic knowledge" comes from.